# Getting blank page while using React Router Dom & two copies of the react package and error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I got many errors while using React router dom in my application. Now, I am getting nothing but blank page.

error in console

```
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

```
The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:

    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5179:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:44:74)

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

I used npm ls react in terminal. I get that info from here: (https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning). But I do not have any idea what does it mean.

```
PS C:\Users\MAHELAKA\React> npm ls react
React@ C:\Users\MAHELAKA\React
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.10.0
  ├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  ├─┬ react-router@6.10.0
  │ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
  └── react@18.2.0
```

My App.js code:

```
import "./App.css";
import Alert from "./components/Alert";
import About from "./components/About";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import TextForm from "./components/TextForm";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";


// import About from "./components/About"
function App(props) {
  const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
  const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

  const showAlert = (message, type) => {
    setAlert({
      msg: message,
      type: type
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAlert(null);
    }, 2000);
  };

  const toggleMode = () => {
    if (mode === "light") {
      setMode("dark");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#011121";
      document.body.style.color = "white";
      showAlert("dark mode has been enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils - Dark Mode'
    } 
      else {
      setMode("light");
      document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.body.style.color = "black";
      showAlert("white mode has been enabled", "success");
      document.title = 'TextUtils - Light Mode'
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Router>
      <Alert alert={alert} />
      <div className="container my-3">
      <Routes>
          <Route path="/about"  element={<About/>} />
          
          <Route path="/" element={<TextForm showAlert={showAlert} 
            heading="Enter The Text To Analyze Below" />} />
         
     
        </Routes>
        </div>
        </Router>
           </>
  );
}
export default App;
```

I am new to React, pls help me. How can I resolve this issue? I would be grateful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see here is with the JSX you are trying to write. `element` is a prop of the `Route` component, move it into the `Route` component tag so the route has content to render when the path matches the URL path.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Alert alert={alert} />
  <div className="container my-3">
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
      <Route
        path="/"
        element={(
          <TextForm
            showAlert={showAlert}
            heading="Enter The Text To Analyze Below"
          />
        )}
      />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: I tried that but it is still not working. Thank you though.

Comment: @MahelakaMansoori I don't see any other issue with the code you shared. See if 
 you can create a ***running*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue you describe that we could inspect live.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/76004277/21541328

Comment: Kindly, go through the above link. It may give you the clue that is making the hurdle in my code. Thank you!