# Why am I getting Blank page, 4 times: Invalid hook call & error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I got this error in the console. (4 times at a time)

```
react.development.js:209 Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside  
the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this 
problem.
```

I also got this error in the console but 1 time

```
    The above error occurred in the <BrowserRouter> component:
    at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:5177:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3001/static/js/bundle.js:44:74)

   Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
   Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

I gave this command in the terminal on behalf of React dev but I do not have any idea what to do now after this.

```
    PS C:\Users\MAHELAKA\React> npm ls react       
React@ C:\Users\MAHELAKA\React
└─┬ react-router-dom@6.10.0
├─┬ react-dom@18.2.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
├─┬ react-router@6.10.0
│ └── react@18.2.0 deduped
└── react@18.2.0
```

my app.js

```
  import "./App.css";
  import Alert from "./components/Alert";
  import About from "./components/About";
  import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
  import TextForm from "./components/TextForm";
  import React, { useState } from "react";
  import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";


function App(props) {
const [mode, setMode] = useState("light");
const [alert, setAlert] = useState(null);

const showAlert = (message, type) => {
  setAlert({
  msg: message,
  type: type,
 });
 setTimeout(() => {
  setAlert(null);
 }, 2000);
};

const toggleMode = () => {
if (mode === "light") {
  setMode("dark");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#011121";
  document.body.style.color = "white";
  showAlert("dark mode has been enabled", "success");
  document.title = "TextUtils - Dark Mode";
} 
  else {
  setMode("light");
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  document.body.style.color = "black";
  showAlert("white mode has been enabled", "success");
  document.title = "TextUtils - Light Mode";
   }
};

 return (
  <>
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Navbar
      title="TextUtils"
      mode={mode}
      toggleMode={toggleMode}
      aboutText="About"
    />
    <Alert alert={alert} />
    <div className="container my-3">
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />

        <Route
          path="/"
          element= { <TextForm showAlert={showAlert}  heading="Enter The Text To Analyze 
     Below" mode={mode} />
          }
        />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
</>
);
}

 export default App;
```

[![I installed more than one package, I guess. I checked node_modules. Both have
contained different files ][1]][1]

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaoxO.png
```

Please, help me. I would be grateful to those who help me out. I am getting blank page and some errors. How could I fix it?

Comment: Can you share your package.json file?

Comment: I did not do anything with package.json file.

Comment: You can try deleting the node_modules file and `npm install` if you're sure about dependencies.

Comment: I had done that it was throwing an error. So reinstall that. As I have have more than one node_modules file so I am confused which one should I delete now.

Comment: You should have only one `node_modules` directory and one package.json file per project. Looks like you created a second, nested project inside *some* `textutils` directory. This seems like a mistake. Might be better to save the current project's application code, entirely delete the project, recreate the project with `create-react-app` or whatever you are using, and copy the app files back into the `src` directory. Does this all make sense?

Comment: @DrewReese It didn't work.